# Is there a way to convert ASCII MathML to LaTeX?

Tags: latex, mathml

I would like to know if there is a way to convert ASCII MathML to LaTeX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know of two tools that might be able to help you here.

The first is [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/)

The second is [Sciwriter](http://sciwriter.en.softonic.com/)

The later is a bit old, but might be the best bet if you are on windows. Pandoc is cross-platform.

Comment: Do you know of any programs tools that takes in asciimathml as its input and converts it to latex?

Comment: @xinyichua sorry i don't